# Database not storing the Greek Characters correctly

Tags: php, mysql

Good afternoon one and all,

I've recently deployed a website on a remote server, and using the same mySQL creation script, created a database. Two of the fields need to display Greek Characters, and so their collation is set to greek_general_ci.  This works fine on my local dev machine (which is the same as the set up on the server, probably a few security settings are different.)  However...

I've gone to add some stuff to the data base, and all I'm getting in the data base is ????? instead of the greek character Unicode codes that I get on my local machine.

I've checked that the server has the collations on, and the correct character sets.  And I've googled for the answer, but alas I've had no success.  I was wondering if it was something I could fix, or should I contact the server admin for them to have a look at it?  As I don't want to mess around with the server settings, as there's a live website running off the same data base engine.

Many thanks in advance.

I've been asked to post the code here, so this is the code as it stands.

AddWord.html  I've only added the form, as that's all that needs to be seen.

```
<form name="addwrd" action="addWord.php" method="post">
                        <label for="greek_word">Greek Word</label>
                        <input type="text" onkeyup="trans(this.id)" id="greek_word" name="GreekWord" size=30><br><br>                        
                        <label for="greek_definition">Greek Definition</label>  
                        <input type="text" onkeyup="trans(this.id)" id="greek_definition" name="GreekDefinition" size=30><br><br>
                        <label for="EnglishWord">English Word</label>
                        <input type="text" name="EnglishWord" size=30><br><br>
                        <label for="EnglishDefinition">English Word</label>
                        <input type="text" name="EnglishDefinition" size=30><br><br>
                        <label for="chapter">Chapter</label>
                        <input type="text" name="chapter" size=20><br><br>
                        <label for="section">Section</label>
                        <input type="text" name="section" size=20><br><br>
                        <label for="hint">Hint</label>
                        <input type="text" name="hint" size=50><br><br>
                        <input type="submit" name="addword" value="Submit">
                    </form>
```

AddWord.php

```
include_once( 'admin_dataHandler.php' );

$dataHandler = new DataConnection();

/** 
 * The variables we're getting back from the HTML form we've just filled
 * in.
 */
$greekWord = $_POST['GreekWord'];
$greekDef = $_POST['GreekDefinition'];
$englishWord = $_POST['EnglishWord'];
$englishDef = $_POST['EnglishDefinition'];
$chapter = $_POST['chapter'];
$section = $_POST['section'];
$hint = $_POST['hint'];

$dataHandler->addWord($greekWord, $greekDef, $englishWord, $englishDef, $chapter, $section, $hint);
// The header should redirect to the admin index.html page.
```

And this is the code from the data handler that adds the word to the data base.

```
function addWord($grkWrd, $grkDef, $engWord, $engDef, $chptr, $sects, $hint){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO word (GreekWord, GreekDefinition, EnglishWord, EnglishDefinition, Chapter, Sections,Hint) values (:grkWrd,:grkDef,:engWrd,:engDef,:chptr,:sctn,:hnt)";
            $stmt = $this->dataHandler->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bindParam(':grkWrd', $grkWrd , PDO::PARAM_STR, 45);
            $stmt->bindParam(':grkDef', $grkDef , PDO::PARAM_STR, 45);
            $stmt->bindParam(':engWrd', $engWord , PDO::PARAM_STR, 45);
            $stmt->bindParam(':engDef', $engDef , PDO::PARAM_STR, 45);
            $stmt->bindParam(':chptr', $chptr , PDO::PARAM_STR, 45);
            $stmt->bindParam(':sctn', $sects , PDO::PARAM_STR, 45);
            $stmt->bindParam(':hnt', $hint , PDO::PARAM_STR, 45);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
```

I hope this provides further information, my apologies for not posting the code the first time out.

Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Welshboy

Comment: "*I've gone to add some stuff to the data base*". How? Through PHP code? PHPmyAdmin? Direct access to MySQL?

Comment: I'm adding the data via a HTML form, that sends it to a PHP file that acts as an interface between the HTML and the data_admin_handler.php file, which contains the sql query.  However this worked fine on the local dev machine...which is what I'm finding odd.

Comment: A nice read (if you haven't already read it): http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: I'll have a read of that now, thanks for the link :-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that all of those Greek characters should be contained within UTF8 and that'd you'd save yourself some grief by setting everything up to use UTF8.

You talked about Greek character unicode codes but the `greek` collation isn't unicode, it's `ISO 8859-7` (see [Character Sets and Collations That MySQL Supports](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html))

I wrote an article on character set problems with PHP/MySQL just a few days ago which I think could have some relevant information. [How to Avoid Character Encoding Problems in PHP](http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/how-to-avoid-character-encoding-problems-in-php/)

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, when I look in my data base, this is what I see:  &#964;&#949;&#963;&#964;  But on the remote site I get ???????  I thought they were unicode but clearly I'm wrong, thanks for the correction

Comment: the ??? are where MySQL has tried to translate characters from one charset to another (where the connection charset differs from the table's collation)

Comment: In the end, I changed the encoding on the fields to utf8_unicode_ci and this seemed to fix the issue.  I had to do this in the myPHPAdmin.

Just wanted to say thanks for taking the time to respond, and @JamesC your answer got me moving in the right direction.  Excellent blog post.  Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt it's the database that's the problem. You should double check your code, or post it here, because that's by far the most likely culprit.